# how to display new songs along with old songs in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

```
-(void) mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    NSURL* assetUrl = [mediaItemCollection.representativeItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetUrl options:nil];

    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

    myPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    collectionMutableCopy = [mediaItemCollection.items mutableCopy]; 
    [self.myPlaylistTable reloadData];

    //[self updatePlayerQueueWithMediaCollection: mediaItemCollection];
    [myPlayer play]; 

}
```

I have a Button that allows me to select select songs from Iphone Library. I have another UIButton where it shows the list of selected songs from ipod Library.

I am displaying the selected songs in **UITableview** which is **myPlaylistTable** 
when i select say two songs from iPod Library those two songs get displayed **myPlaylistTable** but problem happens when I try to add few more songs the two songs which was displayed earlier got disappear.

For ex if i select two songs first time and If I add another two songs it should show four songs .

Answer (score 0):

Please considering doing the following.... It should help and resolve your problem.

> self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

That will keep the row selected, unless you manually deselect the row or the user selects another row on the table.